# Is it possible to do a PhD in ML or AI while in industry, sponsored by a company, or for a company?

Tags: phd, computer-science

I'm due to finish my MSc in CS within a few months and have a key focus on ML and AI research. The problem I'm currently facing is I have no idea where to go from here.

I've seen that the vast majority of more interesting ML and AI jobs, from the perspective of working on novel algorithms, all require a PhD, whereas implementation of said algorithms is MSc. I'd love to do a PhD but it feels like I would be missing out a lot in the next 3-4 years. I'd also need money to start one.

With that, I was wondering if there is such a thing as a PhD in industry? For example, company "**A**" gives me a position as an ML researcher, and for the next 3-4 years I do work on that. At the end of that time, I obtain a PhD.

Is this something that exists? I'm not trying to look for shortcuts, just listing my options.

Comment: What country, or countries, would you be considering? In Germany I'm told most PhDs of this type are explicitly done with a company, and in the US this is relatively rare full-time, but instead is very normal to have decent funding provided (no cost to you) and then you also have the option to do internships over the summer regularly, in the same company or different companies.

Comment: In germany, the answer is: yes